The usage of 'otherwise'
Is the usage of 'otherwise' in this sentence correct?

I didn't study at all last night. Otherwise, I would have done better on today's test.


It is correct. Get rid of the comma.

The comma doesn't seem wrong to this native speaker…  (Also works without.)

Transient disappearing question asker.

@Lambie The user doesn't have an account on this site, only on ELU

@Dúthomhas It is proper to place a comma after an introductory adverb.  To remove the comma, "otherwise" should be moved elsewhere, like, "I would have otherwise done better on today's test," or, "I would have done better on today's test otherwise."

Adding a comment even if the user doesn't see it: To ask about a word's meaning or usage, please first look it up in a dictionary, and use the "edit" button to tell about what you find there and how it doesn't resolve your question. Questions asking "is this ok" must point to a specific area of concern—that is, please say why you think it might not be okay. This will get more useful answers.

Normally, otherwise introduces a result when something with a "positive spin" is reversed:

Study hard positive spin for that exam; otherwise you won't do well.

It sounds a little odd when it introduces the result when something with a "negative spin" is reversed:

I didn't study hard for the exam. negative spin. Otherwise, I would have done well.

but it sounds OK when it is tacked on as a tail:

I didn't study hard for the exam. I would have done well, otherwise.

I don't think this is just my own idiosyncratic response, since other speakers I've asked feel the same.
Maybe that's because otherwise is frequently associated with urging to do something rather than to refrain from doing something:

Don't go out on that thin ice. Otherwise, you may fall through.  sounds odd
Don't go out on that thin ice. You may fall through otherwise. sounds OK

P.S. What I think it is, after giving it a beer mug of thought, is that "wise" (manner) implies taking a  course of action, not simply taking no action:

Take the parkway, otherwise you'll get stuck in traffic.

But if, on a semantic level, some other course of action is implicit, you can use otherwise with a negative spin:

Don't take the S-10, otherwise you'll get stuck in traffic.

It is not a binary take the S-10/don't take the S-10 scenario but "take the S-10/take some other route" scenario.

Seat-of-the-pants analysis, and fair enough.

The source of many of my ideas, for good or ill.

"Take the parkway" literally makes zero sense here in the UK.  I had to look up "parkway" which is defined as a landscaped thoroughfare. I still have no idea what that is! Is it just a scenic road, a pleasant avenue?  A road through a park? A road with grass verges?  I'm totally lost. LOL.

@BillyKerr - it's a kind of 1900-1920s American early motorway for commuter or leisure travel between a city and surrounding areas suburbs and a central city. Landscaped with leafy views on both sides. The M32 which joins Bristol to the M4 was named 'the Parkway' in 1972 when it opened, but the name mainly survives at Bristol Parkway station, near the M4/M32 junction. The name has definitely not caught on in the UK, except that  Peterborough and Plymouth have roads branded as "parkways" which provide routes for much through traffic and local traffic. Most are dual carriageways.

@MichaelHarvey Yeah, that's what I kind of understood - associated it with park and ride railway stations.  There's a Parkway Metrolink park and ride in Manchester.  Luton Airport Parkway railway station.  So, in the American sense it's essentially what we would call a dual carriageway (rather than a motorway).

Do a Google Maps street view of Taconic Parkway and Garden State Parkway to get a sense of the range of possibilities.

@TimR - Interesting.  I suppose we'd just call those a dual carriageway in the UK.  These kind of roads are slightly lower grade than a motorway which would be more or less equivalent perhaps to a US interstate highway.

+1 I'm happy to upvote any thinking derived from a beer mug!

None of this actually answers the question and it is full of personal preference.

@Dúthomhas That's a harsh judgement, and -- to me -- false as far as answering the question is concerned (it does answer it).

Interestingly, Merriam-Webster has an example scraped from the net where "otherwise" introduces a positive alternative outcome (emphases by me): "Fierce headwinds for Tesla   That’s tough luck for Musk’s detractors, such as early Tesla investor and onetime board director Steve Westly, who otherwise would have the perfect opportunity to topple the CEO from his perch. Eva Roytburg, Fortune, 7 June 2024"

@Peter-ReinstateMonica There's the complication of the relative clause ("who otherwise..." so it's not quite the same construction.)   "With these moves, Musk has ensured that no one of his stature can fill his giant shoes. That's tough luck for Musk's detractors...who otherwise would have the perfect opportunity to topple the CEO..."  So otherwise there could be paraphrased as "had Musk not made those moves", i.e. M-W's "in different circumstances".

@BillyKerr In the US, we drive on parkways and park on driveways.
